# online enviornment for visual studio developemnt

Tags: visual-studio-2013

can I get an online work environment for projects development in visual studio, where a user can login from browser and start coding, testing, and deployment to a web server. developers are not required to install visual studio on their local machine. And if its so, is it possible that we can restrict developers from copying in and out anything from that environment(that is not a must to have, but nice to have feature). Plus If  there is a similar environment for  xamarin for visual studio. I am sorry if this is not the right place for such queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A web based IDE is built into Azure. Called "Monaco" it allows you to edit web pages only.

There is no such thing as Visual Studio in the Web yet.